# How can i set text to Multiple edit text in order of position in the Layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm learning android , and now i want to know how to set text to multiple edittext by button click in order of position in the layout.So in [image: this picture] i have buttons which set text to the edit text area in order of position . but how to do this in onclicklistener button's method. Or making the edittext requests the focus if previous one already contains text .

Comment: Hi Gaya, Welcome to SO, Please provide some code that you have implemented so far.

Comment: Hi , i'v just tired with one EditText with unlimited length (it can contain all the text setted when the user clicks) but now i wanna limit the lenghth of each EditText to contain just one letter . sur, i know how to do this , butmy problem is how to program the onClick method to set text to the next empty edit text

Comment: Have you tried edittext.requestFocus();

Comment: but here , i'm not setting text with the keyboard but with buttons , so , i cant request focus in each button onclick , and note that the user will not necessarily click the buttons in order .

Comment: please , take a look to my picture to understand my case , i wanna avoid using if statement in every button onclick method (if edittext 1 is empty ... edittext.settext".."... if edittext is empty settext ".." .if edit text3 is empy ..settext"..." here a have at last 10 buttons so i wanna avoid repeating this for each button . i'll be gratful for youtr answer .

Comment: Post your activity's xml.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps...
Implement a TextWatcher and add textwatcher to all of the EditText, use this inside the afterTextChanged method

```
 for (int i=1; i<=7; i++){ 
    for (int j = 0; j< linearLayout.getChildCount(); j++) {
        if(linearLayout.getChildAt(j) instanceof EditText) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(j); 
            EditText editText2 = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if(editText.getId() == editText2.getId()) { 
                if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) { 
                    //DO YOUR STUFF
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please , take a look to my picture to understand my case , i wanna avoid using if statement in every button onclick method (if edittext 1 is empty ... edittext.settext".."... if edittext is empty settext ".." .if edit text3 is empy ..settext"..." here a have at last 10 buttons so i wanna avoid repeating this for each button . i'll be gratful for youtr answer .

Comment: @GayaTouak try this and let me know.. this will work for what youre looking for